# Select row with no match between two table by id

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have two tables, Table1 and Table2. I want to select distinct rows in Table2 that are not contained in Table1. Here is an example:

```
  Table1

   | Name  |  | id |
   -----------------------
1. | aa |  | 1 |
   ------
2. | bb |  | 1 |
   ------
3. | cc |  | 2 |
   ------
4. | dd |  | 2  |
   ------

Table2

   | name |
   ------
1. | aa |
   ------
2. | aa |
   ------
3. | bb |
   ------
4. | cc |
   ------
5. | cc |
-------------
6. | DD |
   ------
7. | ee |
   ------
8. | ee |
   ------
```

I would want  all row who is not match in two tables when id = 1
like                                                                               result when id = 1
 | name |

### 1. | cc |

### 2. | dd |

### 3. | ee |

I have also attempted rgiht outer  join but it is not differentiate my result when id = 1 or when id = 2

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: i just want query who give all row who is not equal in these two table when id = 1

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear but I think this is what you need

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  
        *
FROM    Table2 t2
        LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
            ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE    ID <> 1 OR ID IS NULL
```